# Try to match multiple values that are in GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: sql, group-concat

```
options_table

options_id    | object_id  |   option_value
=========================================
1            |    1       |    drink
2            |    2       |    ice
3            |    1       |    bath
4            |    2       |    soda
5            |    2       |    drink
6            |    3       |    ice
7            |    4       |    bath
8            |    2       |    bath
9            |    1       |    storm


object_table

object_id    |   object_name
=============================
1            |    sun
2            |    moon
3            |    mars
4            |    jupiter
```

The Query

```
SELECT object_table.object_name GROUP_CONCAT(options_table.option_value ) as object_options 
FROM options_table
LEFT JOIN object_table
ON object_table.object_id = options_table.object_id    
GROUP BY options_table.object_id
```

so i get a result like

```
object_name | object_options
=========================================
moon        | ice, soda, drink, bath
sun         | drink, bath, storm
mars        | ice
jupiter     | bath
```

Lets say the user want all objects that has option "drink" AND option "bath". So i only get this result.

```
object_name | object_options
=========================================
moon        | ice, soda, drink, bath
sun         | drink, bath, storm
```

How do i have to edit the query to get this result?

Comment: Can you say `WHERE 'drink' in object_options AND 'bath' IN object_options`?

Comment: The 'object_options' does not exists yet when trying to access it in the WHERE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b2e3/5

```
select obj.object_name, 
    group_concat(opt.option_value order by opt.options_id) as object_options
from options_table opt
join object_table obj using(object_id)
group by obj.object_id
having sum(opt.option_value in ('drink','bath')) = 2
order by obj.object_name;
```

Output:

```
| OBJECT_NAME |      OBJECT_OPTIONS |
-------------------------------------
|        moon | ice,soda,drink,bath |
|         sun |    drink,bath,storm |
```

---

If you want more ANSI-SQL'y way to do the query, don't rely on MySQLism (boolean/integer duality), use explicit value on SUM instead: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/14cf4/1

```
select obj.object_name, 
    array_agg(opt.option_value order by opt.options_id) as object_options
from options_table opt
join object_table obj using(object_id)
group by obj.object_id, obj.object_name
having sum(case when opt.option_value in ('drink','bath') then 1 end) = 2
order by obj.object_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
SELECT object_name, object_options FROM   
  (SELECT object_table.object_name, 
          GROUP_CONCAT(options_table.option_value ) as object_options
   FROM options_table
   LEFT JOIN object_table
     ON object_table.object_id = options_table.object_id    
   GROUP BY options_table.object_id) t   
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('drink', object_options)> 0 AND  FIND_IN_SET('bath', object_options)> 0
```

Comment: FIND_IN_SET is a serious detour, you can reach the elements in HAVING clause :-) In fact, it has a name for it, [stringly-typed](http://www.google.com/search?q=stringly-typed+programming#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=stringly-typed+programming+-strongly&oq=stringly-typed+programming+-strongly&gs_l=serp.3...4711.7554.0.8750.16.13.3.0.0.0.219.2006.0j12j1.13.0...0.0...1c.hjCEweN09WY&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=b91f5ad55398357e&biw=1280&bih=699) programming

Comment: @MichaelBuen, I was just offering another approach, that's all.  I never said this one was superior.